# how to upload image to s3 bucket

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upload an image named 'quotes.png' to s3 bucket in my Ionic 2 apps (**WITHOUT** using node) but it says 'Network Failure'.

This is how my codes look like (with sensitive info omitted):

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: 'myaccesskeyid', secretAccessKey: 'mysecretaccesskey' })
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {
        Bucket: 'mybucketname',
        Key: 'assets/img/quotes.png',
        Body: "hello"
    };
    s3.putObject(params, function (err, res) {

        if (err) {

            console.log(err);
        } else {
              debugger;
            console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
        }
    });
```

(**UPDATED**)This is the details of the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mybucket-name.s3-ap-southeast-
1.amazonaws.com/assets/img/quotes.png. Response to preflight request doesn't 
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is 
therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Error: Network Failure
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (xhr.js:52)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:227)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at e.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
```

**NOTE**: I am **NOT** using node js in my Ionic 2 app. I am using Parse JavaScript SDK, AWS S3, AWS EC2, Elastic beanstalk and Ionic 2 with Angular 2.

So the question: Did I write my code properly/is there something wrong with my code? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Antoni. Did you request permissions for internet access to the ionic app in config.xml?
<access origin="*" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Hi @Ashan, my app has internet access permission as it can upload file using parse server.

Comment: Did you also setup CORS in S3 bucket allowing  requests from any origin?

Comment: Hi Ashan, the error was solved after setting up the CORS by edting its permission. Btw thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the region where the bucket is located in `AWS.config`.

Example:

```
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
```

Insert this line before the call to `new AWS.S3()`.

Comment: Hi John, i have updated the details of the error in my question. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Go to the AWS console for S3 and setup CORS for your bucket. This is located under the Permissions tab. Make sure that <AllowedHeader>contains an asterisk and <AllowedMethod> has the GET, POST, PUT, etc setup for your needs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Hi John, thank you, the error is gone after setting up the CORS but there is one thing I would like to ask you. The picture i want to upload is named "quotes" and is a png image. Inside my params's Key property, am I right to put 'assets/img/quotes.png' as the image is located inside assets/img directories, or is there something else i must do also?

Comment: Yes, specify the full path as assets/img/quotes.png for the key.  I would also recommend setting the Content-Type for the object to be image/png in your params variable. Add "ContentType: image/png". Notice the spelling for the params value.

Comment: Hi John, I've successfully uploaded the image to my bucket using the putObject. But when I tried to access it from my aws console, it says "We can't open this file". Is the image uploaded defaulted as private or public?

Comment: What method are you using in the AWS S3 Console to open the file (there are several ways)? Does a new browser window or tab open? If true, then the file must be publicly accessible. The default is private but this can be changed during the object upload. Also, the headers must be correct for certain objects like images so that the browser knows what they are in order to display them.

Comment: When I click the url in the S3 console, it automatically downloads the image.

Comment: Actually I want to achieve in my project is: able to upload a file and only the authorized mobile app users can access it. I am trying to use pre-signed url to upload the image using the putObject.

Comment: Presigned URLs are pretty easy to do in just about any language. There are lots of published examples by Amazon and others to help if you need it. Here is a simple example: var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log('The URL is', url);

Comment: Strange. I used this param for putObject. After the putObject code is executed, it will create directory "assets/myImage" in my bucket and inside that directory there is a image named "kokos".jpg. But when i open the image, it just show a black screen. And the console log says 403 forbidden error. The image is opened in a new tab. Here is my param:   Bucket: 'mybucket',
            Key: 'assets/myImage/kokos.jpg',
            Body: "imageFile",
            ACL: "public-read-write",
            ContentType: 'image/jpeg'

Comment: Examine your bucket policy. Think of ACLs as the legacy method and bucket policies as the recommended method. However, ACLs give you object level control whereas Policies provide bucket level control. If either a Policy or an ACL specifies a deny condition, access will be denied. Tip: do not allow public write access to objects.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/

Comment: I tried to use "Action": "s3:*" but the image still gives me a black screen. Here is my bucket policy {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
           "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<replacewithbucketname>/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Examine the headers for the object in the S3 Console. The Content-Type needs to be set correctly. Also press F12 (Chrome) and then refesh. What errors if any are reported in the console. Also, download the image and open in a image program to see if it is corrupted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155747/discussion-between-antoni-and-john-hanley).

Comment: HI John, sorry for late reply. Can I talk to u in the chat room? I have posted some question. Thanks. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155747/discussion-between-antoni-and-john-hanley

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest code of upload images using s3 bucket in aws

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

AWS.config.update({
accessKeyId: "",
secretAccessKey: "",
region:''
});

 router.post('/upload_images_s3', upload.single('image'),  (req,res,next) => {
        res.json('Successfully uploaded  files!')
 });
 
 var maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50;
var  rootFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, './');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'keyfi'}});
var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket: 'keyfi/images',
      acl: 'public-read-write',
      limits: {
        fileSize: maxSize
    },
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null,{fieldName:file.originalname});
        console.log(file);
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
       
        cb(null,file.originalname)
      }
    })
  })
```